# Firebase iOS Swift - retrieve child data corresponding to a chat conversation ID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app using Firebase that displays a list of Questions in a table view. When a user taps on a Question (a cell in the table view), the app segues to another view controller that displays a list of Answers associated to that Question.

This is how I've structured my database's JSON tree:

```
{
 "answers": {
     "question01": {
         "answer01": {
             "name": "kelly"
             "text": "I'm doing great"
         },
         "answer02": {
             "name": "george"
             "text": "never been better"
         }
     }
 },

 "questions": {
     "question01": {
             "name": "courtney"
             "text": "how are you?"
     },
     "question02": {
             "name": "bob"
             "text": "why is the earth round?"
     }
  }
```

I'm able to display the Questions in the first table view no problem with the following code:

```
    // MARK: - Firebase Database Configuration
    func configureDatabase() {//this method gets called in viewDidLoad

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        //listen for new questions in the database
        _refHandle = self.ref.child("questions").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {(snapshot) -> Void in

            self.questionsArray.append(snapshot)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.questionsArray.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        })
    }

    deinit {

        self.ref.child("questions").removeObserverWithHandle(_refHandle)
    }


// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return questionsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell! = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        //unpack question from database
        let questionSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.questionsArray[indexPath.row]
        let question = questionSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
        let name = question[Constants.QuestionFields.name] as String!
        let text = question[Constants.QuestionFields.text] as String!

        cell!.textLabel?.text = name + ": " + text
        cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "ic_account_circle")
        if let photoUrl = question[Constants.QuestionFields.photoUrl], url = NSURL(string:photoUrl), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }

        return cell!
    }
```

Following [Firebase's guide to structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#flatten_data_structures), I'm assuming that I need to retrieve the Answers associated to a Question using the conversation ID that each child in the JSON tree has in common. For example: "question01" would be the conversation ID for the first Question which has two Answers.

How can I retrieve the Answer data associated to each Question so that I can later display those Answers in a table view?

Just to be clear, I'm not asking how to display the data in a table view but rather what is the code to retrieve the Answer data from my Firebase Database associated to a Question's conversation ID.

Comment: Do you want all answers at once or answers corresponding a particular question at a time ?

Comment: A couple of things. 1) you probably don't need removeObserverWithHandle. It appears there's a limited number of questions, so I would suggest using *observeSingleEventOfType(.Value)* to read them in and then iterate over the snapshot to add them to the table.(unless you are wanting to be notified of new questions, then it's fine) 2) Each question has a key:value pair and the key is the name of the question, i.e. 'question01'. When the user taps that question, use pretty much the same code to *observeSingleEventOfType* on answers/question01 to populate the answers tableView.

Comment: @triple.s I would like Answers corresponding to a particular question at a time. For example, going off of the JSON tree I posted above, if a user tapped on `question01`: "how are you?" then the app would segue to a new view controller that displays a table view with the two Answers to `question01` which are "I'm doing great" and "never been better"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways to answer this question.

Given that we have a tableview of questions in the first view controller and the datasource contains the reference to the questions: question01, question02 etc.

Based on the Firebase structure, when a user taps the first question (question01) that node name is passed to the second view controller. It could be assigned to a var within the controller or passed via the segue or even set with a represented object.

In whatever the case, the second view controller would know what question node is (question01 for example), then it's a simple matter of loading the data from Firebase from viewDidLoad and updating the tableView.

```
var questionRef: String() //this will contain question01 for example

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    loadFromFirebase()
}
```

then

```
func loadFromFirebase {

     let ref = answersRef.child(questionRef) //will be answers/question01
     ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

          for child in snapshot.children {

            let key = child.key as String
            let text = child.value["text"] as! String
            print("answer: \(key)  text: \(text)")
            //add data to a tableViewDataSource
          }
          //reload the tableview
      })
}
```

and the output from this is

```
answer: answer01  text: I'm doing great
answer: answer02  text: never been better
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I'm not ignoring you, I'm just testing out your code and I've run into some separate execution issues that are preventing me to move forward. I'll keep you posted on how your answer worked for me!

Comment: Got it to work, thanks @Jay! Please see detailed answer below.

Comment: How Would I Solve this same Problem, but passing all the info to a model at once? Lets assume I have the same Structure of this problem.

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios I am not sure I understand that question. In the OP and my answer, we are passing the parent node name (key) to the views with the answer so that can be used to retrieve the answers for the question. I would need to know what 'all the info' and 'model' are before I could formulate an answer. Your question may be different enough to ask it as a separate question,

Comment: @Jay you are right! I did ask it now! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995752/retrieving-from-firebase-database-with-multiple-childs

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Jay's answer above, I was able to get the Firebase Answers to populate in the second table view after a long struggle.

1. Pass the Firebase JSON node name (`questionSnapshot.key`) associated to the Question (cell) that a user tapped on into a property named `questionRef` in the `AnswersViewController`:

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if segue.identifier == Constants.Segues.HomeToAnswersNavController {
           guard let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
           let questionSnapShot: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.questionsArray[selectedIndexPath.row]
           let selectedQuestion = questionSnapShot.key

           guard let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? AnswersViewController else { return }
           destinationVC.questionRef = selectedQuestion
       }
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       performSegueWithIdentifier(Constants.Segues.HomeToAnswersNavController, sender: self)
   }
   ```
2. Configure database in the AnswersViewController and load data in the second Answers table view (I chose to use `observeEventType: withBlock` instead of `observeSingleEventOfType: withBlock:` since I want to be notified of new Questions and Answers getting added to the database):

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
   self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableViewCell")
   self.configureDatabase()
   }

   deinit {
   self.ref.child("answers").child(questionRef!).removeObserverWithHandle(_refHandle)
   }

   func configureDatabase() {
   self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
   _refHandle = self.ref.child("answers").child(questionRef!).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
       self.answersArray.append(snapshot)
       self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.answersArray.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
   })
   }


   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return self.answersArray.count
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell: UITableViewCell! = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
   //unpack question from database
   let answerSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.answersArray[indexPath.row]
   let answer = answerSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
   let name = answer[Constants.AnswerFields.name] as String!
   let text = answer[Constants.AnswerFields.text] as String!
   cell!.textLabel?.text = name + ": " + text
   cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "ic_account_circle")
   if let photoUrl = answer[Constants.QuestionFields.photoUrl], url = NSURL(string:photoUrl), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
       cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
   } 
   return cell!
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget this last step! I spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure out why I the Answer data wouldn't display in my table view because I had forgotten to publish a set of database rules in the Firebase console allowing read/write permissions:

   [Screenshot of my Firebase console showing updated Database Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOGOl.png)

That worked for me. Please let me know if this helps your Firebase project! And again, thank you @Jay for helping me solve this.