# Retrieving From Firebase Database with multiple childs

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working with Firebase for a while with no problem, but Recently I have a database structure with multiple childs, And Im having issues reading it on my code.
Here is my Firebase Database Structure:

```
{
  "news" : {
    "50OzNLsK" : {
      "category" : "Anuncio",
      "content" : [ null, {
        "paragraph" : {
          "text" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        }
      }, {
        "quote" : {
          "image" : "http://www.magonicolas.cl",
          "quoteText" : "textoDelQuote"
        }
      } ],
      "date" : "Hoy",
      "imgURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rinnofeed.appspot.com/o/images%2Ftanta.jpg?alt=media&token=60f18a95-9919-4d81-ab1c-9976b71590fc",
      "likes" : 12,
      "summary" : "Este es el resumen de la noticia",
      "title" : "Mi NUeva noticia",
      "videoURL" : "https://youtu.be/S0YjUc7K3cw"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "tfeMODxXUnVvhvzntm77pKKtyfz2" : {
      "email" : "magonicolas@gmail.com",
      "store" : "Rinno"
    },
    "tpjn4feUuiTJmsd9lslHTREG1iE2" : {
      "email" : "nicolas.palacios@rinno.la",
      "store" : "Rinno"
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is reading the internal information, for example the text in 500zNLsK/content/1/parahraph/text or the quote text in 500zNLsK/content/2/quote/quoteText

I have come this far:

```
DataService.ds.REF_NEWS.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

            self.news = []


            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot
                {
                    if let newsDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                    {
                        print("Mago Dict: \(newsDict)")

                        let key = snap.key
                        let new = News()
                        new.configureNews(newsKey: key, newsData: newsDict)
                        self.news.append(new)

                    }
                }
            }
```

And I can't make appear the inside content, it gives null.
Help would me much appreciated :D

Comment: Please share the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have Edited now @FrankvanPuffelen but I didn't won't to because I want to se if someone just have a better way to read that Database from firebase.

Comment: Can  you please replace your Firebase structure with text. That will help us to not have to retype your structure if we are testing it or posting an answer which may include a snippet.

Comment: Good Idea @Jay I have just done it!

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen   Could you please [read my question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212468) as I don't know how to read deeper into the  snapshot I received from Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of changes you will need to make to your structure to have it work fluidly.  Here's an example structure to get you going the right direction:

```
  "news"
    "topic_1"
      "category" : "topic 1 category"
      "content"
        "content_1"
          "paragraph"
            "text" : "topic 1 content 1 text"
        "content_2"
          "paragraph"
            "text" : "topic 1 content 2 text"
      "date" : "some date",
      "likes" : 12

    "topic_2"
      "category" : "topic 2 category",
      "content"
        "content_1"
          "paragraph"
            "text" : "topic 2 cotent 1 text"
        "content_2"
          "paragraph"
            "text" : "topic 2 content 2 text"
      "date" : "another date",
      "likes" : 425
```

Here's the commented code to get to the 'inside' most data

```
  newsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    if ( snapshot!.value is NSNull ) {
        print("not found")
    } else {

        for child in (snapshot?.children)! {

            //snapshots are each node withing news: topic_1, topic_2
            let snap = child as! FDataSnapshot 

            //get each nodes data as a Dictionary
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject] 

            //we can now access each key:value pair within the Dictionary
            let cat = dict["category"]
            print("category = \(cat!)")

            let likes = dict["likes"]
            print("  likes = \(likes!)")

            //the content node is a key: value pair with 'content' being the key and
            //  the value being a dictionary of other key: value pairs
            let contentDict = dict["content"] as! [String: AnyObject]

            //notice that the content_1 key: value pair has a key of content_1 
            //   and a value of yet another Dictionary
            let itemNum1Dict = contentDict["content_1"] as! [String: AnyObject]

            //new we need to get the value of content_1, which is
            //  'paragraph' and another key: value pair
            let paragraphDict = itemNum1Dict["paragraph"] as! [String: AnyObject]

            //almost there.. paragraphDict has a key: value pair of
            //   text: 'topic 1 content 1 text'
            let theText = paragraphDict["text"] as! String
            print("  text = \(theText)")

        }
    }
})
```

Some notes:

1) PLEASE don't user arrays in Firebase. They are evil and will cause you great grief. Your node names should be something describing the node (like 'news') and the child values created with childByAutoId. Even within the 'content' node I used content_1 and content_2 but those should also be created with childByAutoId

2) If you are iterating over nodes as in my example, the structure within the nodes should remain consistent. You can actually get around this a bit but for queries etc you are always better off being consistent.

3) [Denormalizing is Normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html). This structure works but you would gain some advantages making the entire structure shallower.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed help!, But If I have n content, how would you loop through that

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios what is 'n' content? The code in my answer handles cases where there is no data, or if it's 1 to x number of children.

Comment: @Jay   Could you please have a look here at my question [on stackoverflow as I am having a hard time reading the data from my snapshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212468) . Many thanks